# HTML5 video custom controls for any number of videos on the page

Tags: javascript, html, video, controls

mates!

I was needed a simple text button – "Play". It should be hidden if video is playing and should be visible when video ends. Everything works fine, but it works only if I have one video on the page with unique ID.

HTML:

```
<video id="main-video" width="640" height="480">
    <source src="media//mp4/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<span id="custom-play-button">Play</span>
```

And here is the JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var video = document.getElementById("main-video");
    var playButton = document.getElementById("custom-play-button");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById('main-video').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
            video.play();
            playButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
            function myHandler(e) {
                playButton.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });
    }
```

But what should I do if there will be 4,5,6...100 videos on the page (and there will be)? I can't handle with 100 unique ID...

Comment: use `document.getElementsByTagName("video")`

Comment: I was thinking about that. But how do I match any custom "Play" button with the right video?

Comment: just put it next to the video tag and use `.nextSibling` `http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp`

Comment: try this code http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/83sL1b0u/1/

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I will use @11thdimension code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put every video and button in a parent div tag as below.

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="main-video" width="640" height="480">
        <source src="media//mp4/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <span id="custom-play-button">Play</span>
</div>
```

I'm using jQuery code, you can translate it to plain JS easily.
This should work.

```
$(".video-container").each(function () {
    var video = $(this).find("video");
    var plainVideo = video.get(0);/*DOM video object, unwrapped from jQuery*/
    var playBtn = $(this).find("span");

    playBtn.click(function () {
        video.get(0).addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
        plainVideo.play();
        playBtn.css("visibility", "hidden");

        function myHandler(e) {
            playBtn.css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    });
});
```

At least this will give you an idea about the approach to this problem.

Comment: Working awesome! Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 0):

**With pure Javascript (No jQuery)**

You should but depend on the `id`, use the tag for reference, and get the nearest `span`. See the below code.

```js
function closest(el, sel) {
    if (el != null) return el.matches(sel) ? el : (el.querySelector(sel) || closest(el.parentNode, sel));
}

var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
for (i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
    var video = videos[i];
    var playButton = closest(video, "span");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById('main-video').addEventListener('ended', myHandler, false);
        video.play();
        playButton.style.visibility = "hidden";
        function myHandler(e) {
            playButton.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<video width="640" height="480">
    <source src="media//mp4/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<span class="custom-play-button">Play</span>

<video width="640" height="480">
    <source src="media//mp4/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<span class="custom-play-button">Play</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use CSS `class`es rather that `id`'s and you have to use JavaScript to listen for video events and have your custom controls such as playpause button toggle. JavaScript's `event.target` tells you which video is doing what. MDN has a great article [Creating a cross-browser video player](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Fundamentals/Audio_and_video_delivery/cross_browser_video_player) which includes detailed instructions for custom controls for a single video.

#### Automated

I spent a few days creating a JavaScript that automates custom controls (Google's [Material Design](https://material.io/design/) UI) for any number of videos on your HTML page.

The readable source code is on github at [rhroyston/material-controls-for-html-video](https://github.com/rhroyston/material-controls-for-html-video).

Fairly complex to do, but as you can see, it can be done.  Live working demo is at https://hightechtele.com/articles/material-controls-for-html-video

Finally, like I said, this took me a few days. It's easy to do by hand for a single video but wanted to automate/script it. ...So view the script (and small accompanied CSS) to see how it can be done.

[image]